# LocalJumpError (no block given), jRuby, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error "LocalJumpError (no block given)" any time when I paste this row of code to my index function in rails controller:

```
result = Neo4j.query("START n=node(0) RETURN n")
```

So the function looks like (function has no objective, it's only for testing purposes of Neo4j.query)

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all

  result = Neo4j.query("START n=node(0) RETURN n")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json @posts }
  end
end
```

Neo4j.query should return just "enumerable of hash values" as stands in its documentation ([Neo4j.query documentation](http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/Neo4j.html#method-c-query))

The error LocalJumpError (no block given) occurs with jruby v. 1.7, with jruby v. 1.6.2 error changes to ArgumentError (block not supplied)

Comment: Isn't the node arg mandatory?

Comment: You mean the second argument of query function? I tryed with it but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found myself using an old documentation for neo4j.rb by mistake. Documentation for v. 2 is at https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/wiki